# How can I allow CORS using many ports?

Tags: go, gorilla, mux

I came across this code and would like to allow CORS on port 1111,1112 and 1113 how can I do that?

```
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/all", All).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/gotoT", Goto).Methods("GET")
headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"})
origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1111", handlers.CORS(headers, methods, origins)(router)))
```

In this example, **CORS is listening only on port 1111**, **so I would like to add more ports**, please any help?

Comment: In this example, the http-server is listening on port 1111. You want the same server to run on different ports at the same time? Maybe port forwarding is a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in separate go routines:

```golang
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/all", All).Methods("GET")
router.HandleFunc("/gotoT", Goto).Methods("GET")
headers := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
methods := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "POST", "PUT", "HEAD", "OPTIONS"})
origins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})

corsRouter := handlers.CORS(headers, methods, origins)(router)

go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1111", corsRouter))
}()

go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1112", corsRouter))
}()

log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1113", corsRouter))
```